# evaluate text present in specific format in another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have a text written as "12*14" in C4 and and number "1000" in B4.
I want to calculate D4 as 1000-12*14

I have tried following, But both are not working here.

*B4-NUMBERVALUE(C4)*

*B4-VALUE(C4)*

Comment: Will the text always be in the form of number*number?

Comment: `12*14` can be solved but using VBA macro and the NUMBERVALUE can't solve this!

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, It will be always like number*number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the *Text* into a *Number*.  In **D4** enter:

```
=B4-LEFT(C4,FIND("*",C4)-1)*MID(C4,FIND("*",C4)+1,99)
```

[image]

The factors:

```
LEFT(C4,FIND("*",C4)-1)     isolates the 12
MID(C4,FIND("*",C4)+1,99)   isolates the 14
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the "Formulas" tab in the ribbon and click on "Name Manager"
2. Click on "New" on the top right of the "Name Manger" window
  3.

[image: IMG:]

Enter any name you want, I used "anything"

In the "Refers To" section type the following formula 
"=evaluate(Sheet1!$C$4)" and click "OK"

4. Close the "Name Manager" window
5. Go to the cell where you want to output the data (cell D4) in your case, then enter the following :

```
=B4-anything
```

(anything was the name I entered in the Name Manager)

Comment: This is good, But i have to perform for every cell i.e. B - C and it does not work drag down, like function work in Excel